# In Bootstrap UI datepicker focus is not returning back to the date field when clicked on a date

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

When I click on `Today, clear` or `close` button the focus comes back to `date field`.
I want same functionality when I click on any particular date.

Comment: Care to show us your code, or are we expected to guess it ourselves?

Comment: actually the application is very huge. And we are also using our customize focus. Just wanted to know if we can override the $scope.select function outside the bootstrap.js file .

Comment: Try this http://plnkr.co/edit/Dyh6knZ88XiXtVrRNfQS?p=preview (https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/5027)

Comment: found the answer. Posted as answer. :) Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Debugged the issue. Found that in date picker itself the functionality is not present to bring back the focus on date field once a date is selected.
**Datepicker Popup :** http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Found out that in file: datepicker.js, the function `$scope.select = function(date)` is getting triggered when we click on any date, which in turns broadcasts a event `$scope.$broadcast('uib:datepicker.focus');` which is not getting caught anywhere in our code.

Below is the code to fix:

```
  var focusElement = function() {
    self.element[0].focus();
  };

  // Listen for focus requests from popup directive
  $scope.$on('uib:datepicker.focus', focusElement);
```

Link which helped : https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/datepicker/datepicker.js#L213